# Count blank cells in query formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am ranking answer for a form. and I came up with this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({'LEADs oGV'!U:U,LEN('LEADs oGV'!U:U)},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 3",
 0))
```

The problem is that it does not count the number of blank answers in the given column! How can I do that without filling every single blank cell?

Comment: Can you share a sheet with us Brites and show us your expected outcome, so we can have a look?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dn2w6DaF7JikIo1EOp4BE6XokRUOK5GogTFvIff_Lk/edit?usp=sharing 

Here it is! The tables in "Publico oGV", takes input from "LEADs oGV", which is exported from my company's  software

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({'LEADs oGV'!U:U,LEN('LEADs oGV'!U:U)},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 4",0))
```